# Tree like view of Triplets and remove URI's

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jena, ontology

I have written a code in java that reads the ontology and print the triplets. the code is working fine. i want to hide the URI's in output and also print the output in the tree hierarchy form. Currently it gives me output in lines. Any idea how can i do this.

```
Tree Form Like:

Thing
     Class
         SubClass
            Individual
              so on ...
```

this is the ReadOntology class, this class i use in servlet.

```
public class ReadOntology {

    public static OntModel model;

    public static void run(String ontologyInFile) {

        model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, null);
        InputStream ontologyIn = FileManager.get().open(ontologyInFile);

        loadModel(model, ontologyIn);
    }

    protected static void loadModel(OntModel m, InputStream ontologyIn) {
        try {
             m.read(ontologyIn, "RDF/XML");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

this is the servlet

```
public class Ontology extends HttpServlet{

    OntClass ontClass = null;

    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException
    {

        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        ServletContext context = this.getServletContext();
        String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/Data/taxi.owl");
        ReadOntology.run(fullPath);

        SimpleSelector selector = new SimpleSelector(null, null, (RDFNode)null);

        StmtIterator iter = ReadOntology.model.listStatements(selector);
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
           Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();
           out.print(stmt.getSubject().toString());
           out.print(stmt.getPredicate().toString());
           out.println(stmt.getObject().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one step towards your goal, this groups the statements by subject, and for the predicates only shows the local name:

```java
ResIterator resIt = ReadOntology.model.listSubjects()
while (resIt.hasNext()) {
    Resource r = resIt.nextResource();
    out.println(r);
    StmtIterator iter = r.listProperties();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();
        out.print("   ");
        out.print(stmt.getPredicate().getLocalName());
        out.println(stmt.getObject());
    }
}
```

There are lots of useful methods in the API for [Resource](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html) and [Model](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Model.html).

To render a full class tree, use the methods on [OntModel](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntModel.html) and [OntClass](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntClass.html). Perhaps:

```
private void printClass(Writer out, OntClass clazz, int indentation) {
   String space = '    '.repeat(indentation);

   // print space + clazz.getLocalName()
   ...
   // iterate over clazz.listSubClasses(true)
   // and call printClass for each with indentation increased by 1
   ...
   // iterator over clazz.listInstances()
   // and print all their properties as in the
   // snippet above but with space added
}
```

Then in the service method, iterate over the OntModel's classes, and for any where `hasSuperClass()` is false, call `printClass(out, clazz, 0)`.

Comment: Yes, it display the name. Thankyou.  now the second part of my question.

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. “In the tree hierarchy form”, what do you mean by that? If you edit your question with a clearer explanation, then maybe someone cane help.

Comment: Yes that's much clearer. I've updated my answer with a sketch of an approach. Good luck!

Comment: Thankyou for your help.